# content narration in web page, on tab press not going to speak anything if current task(speak anything) not completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using articulate.js(http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-jQuery-Based-Text-To-Speech-Engine-Articulate-js/) to read content from page and speak it. It is working fine, just not works if it is speaking something and I have press tab then it stops but not reads tab selected content.
some pre-define functions

```
<script>
function speak(obj) {
  $(obj).articulate('speak');
};

function pause() {
  $().articulate('pause');
};

function resume() {
  $().articulate('resume');
};

function stop() {
  $().articulate('stop');
};
</script>
```

what I have tried

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      counter +=1;
      if (counter == 1){
        explode();
      }
    },1000);
    function explode(){
      //$('body').articulate('speak'); // Default for play whole content
      $('h1').articulate('speak');
    }

    $('body').keyup(function (e) {
    $().articulate('stop');
      if (e.which == 9) { // on tab press start speaking selected element
        var i=document.activeElement.id;
        $('#'+i).articulate('pause').articulate('stop').articulate('speak');
      }
      else{ // trying to speak what key has been pressed except tab, but not working
          var i=document.activeElement.id;
          $('#'+i).val().articulate('speak');
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

I am also trying to make it audible(to speak keypress) on text box, which is not working

Answer (score 0):

I have make some changes now it is working, but it has certain limitation like it not reads backspace, ctrl, space etc but speak a to z,1 to 0, very well. please improve it

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      counter +=1;
      if (counter == 1){
        explode();
      }
    },1000);
    function explode(){
      //$('body').articulate('speak'); // Default for play whole content
      $('h1').articulate('speak');
    }

    $('body').keyup(function (e) {
        var speaking = $().articulate('isSpeaking');
        var paused = $().articulate('isPaused');
//  $().articulate('stop');
      if (e.which == 9) {
          if (speaking) {
              $().articulate('pause');
              $().articulate('stop');
          }

          var check =0;
          setTimeout(function(){
              check +=1;
              if (check == 1){
                  comeback();
              }
          },1000);
          function comeback() {
              var i=document.activeElement.id;
              $('#'+i).articulate('speak');

          }
      }
      else{
          var i=document.activeElement.id;
          var m=0;
          setTimeout(function () {
              m+=1;
              if(m==1){
                  magic();
              }
          },500);
          function magic() {
              var tempval=$('#'+i).val();
              var lastChar = tempval.substr(tempval.length - 1);
              var ht ='<div>'+lastChar+'</div>';
              $(ht).articulate('speak');
          }
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```